# How to execute a shell command through groovy

Tags: git, shell, groovy, gradle

I want to write a shell command in groovy and execute via gradle. For example, I have this command :

```
git log tag2 tag1
```

This lists the commits done in between two tags. 
I simply want to write this in groovy.
Currently, I am writing like :

```
task show <<                                       
{                                          
    def fist = "git log new-tag4 new-tag5" 
    println("[fist]")                      
    Process process = fist.execute()       
    println(process.text)                  
}
```

This build successfully but doesn't give me the result. Anything  I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/katta/5465317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you are in the right directory:

```
Process process = fist.execute(null, new File("your git repo"))
```

Or:

```
"git log new-tag4 new-tag5".execute(null, new File("C:\Rep9"))
```

Second, make sure you see everything (stdout, stderr) just in case the command has an issue:

```
def process=new ProcessBuilder("git log new-tag4 new-tag5").redirectErrorStream(true).directory(new File("your git repo")).start()
process.inputStream.eachLine {println it}
```

See more at "[Executing shell commands in Groovy](http://www.joergm.com/2010/09/executing-shell-commands-in-groovy/)".

Comment: in the command, do we have to specify the directory name or a file name, coz when I execute the above statement , it says :     Cannot run program "git log new-Tag4 new-Tag3" (in directory "C:\Rep9"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @Sakshi Do you have a .git folder in `C:\Rep9`?

Comment: No, I don't. I have cloned this repo from bitbucket using sourceTree. There is no .git folder

Comment: @Sakshi please pass as a File parameter the path of the repo (the folder which includes a .git inside)

Comment: Ok, But how can I work on this repo then. As in, I want to execute my commands on this repo and I don't have a .git folder

Comment: @Sakshi if you have cloned the repo through stash, you have a .git folder. Try a git status in that folder just to check it is a git repo.

Comment: On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean   This is what I get if I run git status using git cli

Comment: @Sakshi and in which folder are you when you are running that git status?

Comment: I am inside my repo "C:\Rep9" when I run this command on git cli

Comment: But I want to run the command by writing groovy code in a task and then execute that task via gradle on command prompt

Comment: @Sakshi Then my answer (which involves groovy code) stands: `Process process = fist.execute(null, new File("C:\Rep9")) `

Comment: This is working, I get Build Successful! The task runs with no error. But I have no idea where to see the logs? it is not getting displayed in the Command prompt.

Comment: I wrote the task :  task showTwo <<{                                                    
def fist = "git log new-Tag4 new-Tag3"                             
    Process process = fist.execute(null, new File("C:\\Rep9"))    and to execute I used gradlew showTwo on Command prompt

Comment: @Sakshi OK. Try the second form, the one with `ProcessBuilder` and `process.inputStream.eachLine {println it}`

Comment: task showOne  << {  def fist = "git log new-Tag4 new-Tag3"                                                                                                 
 Process process = fist.execute(null, new File("C:\\Rep9"))                                                                       
            def process1 = new ProcessBuilder("git log new-Tag4 new-Tag3").redirectErrorStream(true).directory(new File("C:\\Rep9/build")).start() 
            process1.inputStream.eachLine {println() } }            This way ??

Comment: @Sakshi yes, although you would not need the `process fist` anymore

Comment: Executing task ':showOne' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
:showOne FAILED      I get this output.